# android- error after adding constructor to main class

Tags: android, constructor, runtime-error

When i add constructor in my main class it gives error due to below code. Can i know why? (Without constructor it works fine.)

```
 public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        Button btnShowLocation ;

     private final Context mContext;

            public AndroidGPSTrackingActivity(Context context) {
                    this.mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
                    //tpMethod();
                }

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            Log.d("Main", "class");

            btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
            // show location button click event
            btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(this); 
    }
}
```

Errors:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
java.lang.InstantiationException

Comment: Post the entire logcat trace and related code.

Comment: java.lang.instantiationexception can't instantiate class no empty constructor

Comment: Why are you adding a constructor to an Activity anyways?

Comment: @RaghavSood actually i wanna call a method of my main class in another class, please follow my last post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926742/android-call-method-of-main-class-from-another-class?noredirect=1#comment22688781_15926742

Answer (score 0):

i think your activity is not registered in manifest...

try adding your activity to androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.xyz.Main.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

give this a try...